# Hourly points add to users php and mysql solution?

Tags: php, mysql, time

In the website im working on i need to add user points. Every user will have it's own points and maximum amount of points will be 200. And upon registration user gets 100 points. With various tasks user points will be deducted.

But main problem im struggling is how to add points to the user, since every user need to gets 1 point every hour unless he have 200 or more points.

My first thought was to do a cronjob where it will run every hour a script which will check if user is verified and if user have less than 200 points and add 1 point to every user.

But after some reading im thinking of different approach which i don't understand quite exactly. The better approach, less server resource consuming would be to run a function which will check every time when user login how many points he have and add appropriate number of points to him. Problem is i don't know how to set it, how to calculate how many points to add to user if he was offline like 8 hours and how to time it? Or even maybe use ajax with timer?

What would be your suggestion and approach to this ?

Edit: Just to add since you ask, users doesn't see each other points.

Comment: Will you be showing the user and his/her "points" to other users on a profile page or similar (i.e. when the user is not logged on)? If so, you'll most likely need a job running to do this automatically instead of "on a user action". That, or whenever the user's info is displayed (regardless of who requests it), make the update.

Comment: No, only registered user can see his own points, and they don't need to be visible to other users.

Answer (score 5):

When a user does something, check the last time you gave them points. If it was 5 hours ago, give them 5 points. If it was 10 hours ago, give them 10 points. Etc. Implement caching so if a user visits your site 50 times in one hour, you don't have to check against the DB every time.

Anyway, short answer is, do the check when loading the user data, rather than automatically every hour for all users whether they are active or not.

Comment: That's exactly what i had in mind after some searching, but what troubles me is that website might have 1000 visitors browsing constantly and if each of them load website 20 times per hour, that would be 20 000 more db calls. In other hand using cron if server goes offline for 4 hours users wont get their points.

Comment: Use memcache or something similar to cache a user's info for an hour every time you give them this point. That way, if the cache exists, you don't give them a point, and you don't look up their info again from the db, and if it doesn't... well once an hour per user is very manageable. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE users
SET points = MIN(points + 1, 200)
```

I don't really see the problem with this script running as a cron. Would be more problem if you handled each event as transaction points, since you'd have to run something like:

```
# Generates a row each hour per uncapped user, which may become a lot
INSERT INTO transcations (points, type, created)
SELECT 1, 'HOURLY_INCOME', NOW()
FROM users
WHERE points < 200
```

Is it relevant for other users, or official/inofficial statistics to check what their *current* point is? This is quite relevant, since it won't work fully if it only updates upon login.

Comment: wouldn't MIN just select the one that have minimum amount of points ?

Comment: Indeed. If points are `100`, `MIN(100 + 1, 200)` returns 101. If points are `200`, `MIN(200 + 1, 200)` returns 200.

Answer (score 0):

```
user_table
---------------
id  |  reg_date
1   |  2013-10-10 21:10:15
2   |  2013-10-11 05:56:32
```

Just look how many hours left after user registration, add 100 points:

```
SELECT
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `reg_date`, NOW())+100 AS `p`
FROM
    user_table
WHERE
    id = 1
```

And then check in PHP if result more than 200 just show 200.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, from mysql 5.1 there is neat feature which is basically mysql cron called MySQL Event Scheduler, and i think ill go with that for now since cron script will be very easy to write, small and not time consuming.

All i need to do is to write

```
UPDATE users SET points = (points +1) WHERE points<200
```

And add it to mysql event recurring every hour.